# Use "Any Singer" feature from Docusign SOAP API

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement of using "Any Signer" Docusign feature from API. I am not able to find anything related to this. Does anybody know how to do it from SOAP API?

Comment: Given that your Any Signer users are already set up, you should be able to just set your recipient's name to "Any Signer" and it'll work.  Do you already have an Any Signer group set up and working in the web application?

Comment: The approach of "Any Signer" is the same as adding any recipient to your envelope using the API. I take it that you have followed the steps in the quick start guide (https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Using%20the%20Any%20Signer%20Option.pdf) to ensure that the recipients within the mail group/distribution have setup their DS User accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:  Establish an Any Signer group.

Step 2:  When sending set the name of the recipient to "Any Signer" and use the group email address you configured in Step 1.

---

Here is the PDF guide that shows you how to create Any Signer groups and modify them etc:

[Any Signer](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/quick-start-using-the-any-signer-option.pdf)